# Big git merge - split resolution across commits

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Say I have a `core-master` branch and a `core-client1` branch, that have split a good while ago (>2months).

`core-master` is used by our main product, and `core-client1` was needed for a white-label version for a client. We couldn't merge until now cause of release schedules.

Now that it's possible, I'm merging the `core-client1` changes back to `core-master`.

I would like to "break up" the conflict resolutions into separate commits so they could be reviewed/PR'd separately, and reverted separately if needed.

But since I have conflicts remaining - git won't let me commit some of the files.

I realize I could mark all as resolved and start going back to them - but then I would have to keep track of which files saved myself, and the history would be such that commited conflicts exist in the repo for many of the commit states.

I've searched around for "git partial merge commit" "git split merge" but have only found info about picking certain commits from `core-master`, which is irrelevant in my case.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I can't say how to deal with the current situation, but one of the proper ways to deal with this situation is not to wait with the merges until you're done, for such a long time. A better approach would've been to merge master into your feature branch periodically, so that you could deal with the merge conflicts along the way instead of getting the big one at the end, so consider a different workflow for your next major change.

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't possible in our case. 
I used `feature` for simplicities sake, but the branch was a white-label version for a client - so both branches had to remain stable during development.

Merging would have hurt the stability of master (which needed to produce prod builds during this time)

Comment: Edited my question to explain why merging earlier was not a viable option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to describe a strategy I adopted in a similar situation :

For a time (a few month), we had two versions living side by side :

```
*--x--*--*--*--*--*--* <- master
    \
     A--B--C--D--E--F <- side-version  # the actual nr of commits was more like 100
```

Merging `side-version` in `master` in one go was not feasible.

What I ended up doing was to merge bit by bit :

```
# merging bit by bit :
*--x--*--*--*--*--*--* <- master
    \                 \
     \                 *-----*-----*--* <- fusion
      \               /     /     /  /
       --------------A--B--C--D--E--F <- side-version
```

For ease of use : I didn't commit straight on `master`, I created a `fusion` branch and committed the merging there.

On the history of `side-version`, I listed some key commits (in our case : I used the commits corresponding to released versions), and started merging those versions, one at a time.

Now, since both versions were live, in some cases, the bugs fixed on `side-version` had also been fixed on `master`, so sometimes, "merging" resulted in discarding the content of `side-version` and keeping the version on `master`.

Having isolated points mainly allowed me to :

- solve conflicts on a reduced set of files, and with a scoped changelog, so it was easier to validate the behavior at each step ("the behavior on master, plus a handful of features" rather than "both versions combined")
- merge the unit tests, and validate them on each new merge commit I created
- in some cases, start the server in the current merged state, and check some features on my dev machine

---

The choice of "key commits" really depends on your setup :

- you may have only a handful of commits on `side-version`, which all describe a state where your product is runnable and testable, in which case merging commits one by one is perfectly ok,
- you may have some way to clearly identify "this is where this specific feature was added", "this is where this bug was fixed", and use these,
- you may choose to arbitrarily split the history of `side-version` in ten chunks ...

Whatever suits your needs.

---

The choice of the merge points can also be adapted :

- in my case, it wasn't a stopper to have an absurd commit stating "the version of `master` in august combined with `side-version` in may"
- if you have an incentive to aim at more realistic merges, you can also identify "key commits" on `master` :

```
# an alternative strategy :
*--x---P--Q--R--S--T--U--V <- master
    \      \     \        \
     \   *--*--*--*--*--*--* <- fusion
      \ /     /     /  /
       A--B--C--D--E--F <- side-version
```

---

The merging did take some time (several days), during which the `master` branch evolved. When I reached my first satisfying `fusion` state, I actually had to merge in some extra features and fixes released on `master`.

In our case, it was acceptable to have a history of merged commits. If you have the need however: once you have reached a satisfying state for `fusion`, you may choose to rewrite its history, to split commits in some more meaningful chunks.